# Serverless Database that can be used with the LabVIEW Database Connectivity Kit

Tags: database, labview

I need a compact database, that I can easily deliver with my LabVIEW application. It should have a simple and small installer or work completely without installer.

Currently I am using the Database Connectivity Kit to connect to a firebird database via ODBC. But the performance is really an issue.

I think the best way is a serverless database. But is there a serverless database I can connect to with the Database Connectivity Kit from LabVIEW? Or have you any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It highly depends on the performance which you need from the database, but overall if you need serverless database - I believe that SQLite could be nice choice. Moreover, there is 3rd party free toolkit [SQLite Library by JDP Science](https://www.vipm.io/package/drjdpowell_lib_sqlite_labview/) which you could use to program communication with database.